# Auto complete custom results?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm working on a project where I'm searching locations using Google Maps API v3 places (with auto complete service).

It works nicely and allows you to search from many different countries, how ever I was hoping to add some custom results (e.g. "Mikes place") to the result pane as well (if someone started typing "Mike").

Is it possible to add my own results to the Google Maps places search results or should I use some jQuery auto complete feature and try to add Google results with my own?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a bit late for you but I stumbled across your question before deciding to implement this myself in a [Google Maps Autocomplete component for Angular JS](https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete) which I maintain. Hopefully someone finds it helpful.

Using the component you can specify custom places results which get blended into the results that come back from the AutocompleteService.

Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="example">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Injecting Custom Place Predictions</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/autocomplete.css">

    <!-- Required dependencies -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="lib/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Places Autocomplete directive -->
    <script src="../src/autocomplete.js"></script>

    <script>
        angular.module('example', ['google.places'])

                // Setup a basic controller
                .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.place = null;

                    $scope.myPlaces = [
                        toGooglePlacesResult({
                            label: 'International Airport - T1, Sydney, New South Wales',
                            address: {
                                street: 'International Airport - T1',
                                suburb: 'Sydney',
                                state: 'NSW'
                            },
                            location: { latitude: -33.936722, longitude: 151.164266 }
                        }),
                        toGooglePlacesResult({
                            label: 'Domestic Airport - T2, Sydney, New South Wales',
                            address: {
                                street: 'Domestic Airport - T2',
                                suburb: 'Sydney',
                                state: 'NSW'
                            },
                            location: { latitude: -33.933617, longitude: 151.181630 }
                        }),
                        toGooglePlacesResult({
                            label: 'Domestic Airport - T3, Sydney, New South Wales',
                            address: {
                                street: 'Domestic Airport - T3',
                                suburb: 'Sydney',
                                state: 'NSW'
                            },
                            location: { latitude: -33.933076, longitude: 151.181270 }
                        })
                    ];

                    function toGooglePlacesResult(config) {
                        return {
                            formatted_address: config.label,
                            address_components: [
                                {
                                    long_name: config.address.street,
                                    short_name : config.address.street,
                                    types: [ 'route' ]
                                },
                                {
                                    long_name: config.address.suburb,
                                    short_name: config.address.suburb,
                                    types: [ 'locality' ]
                                },
                                {
                                    long_name: config.address.state,
                                    short_name: config.address.state,
                                    types: [ 'administrative_area_level_1' ]
                                }
                            ],
                            geometry: {
                                location: {
                                    lat: function () { return config.location.latitude },
                                    lng: function () { return config.location.longitude }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Injecting Custom Place Predictions</h1>

            <form class="form">
                <input class="form-control" g-places-autocomplete custom-places="myPlaces" ng-model="place"/>
            </form>

            <h5>Result:</h5>
            <pre>{{place | json}}</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The important parts are making sure your custom places results actually look minimally like a real places result, then wiring up your results to the directive using the `custom-places` attribute.

Comment: How would I use your library with http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps